# How to map a property in C# that is a list?

Tags: c#, list, api, generics, mapping

These are my classes:

```
    public class Registration
    {
        public bool? IsRegistered { get; set; }
        public List<RegistrationProcess> RegistrationProcess { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegistrationProcess
    {
        public bool? PaidInFull { get; set; }
        public double PaymentAmount { get; set; }
        public bool IdentityVerified { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a method that is doing the object mapping like this:

```
public Registration Translate(Services.Registration source)
        {
            return new Registration
            {
                IsRegistered = source.IsRegistered,
                RegistrationProcess = new List<RegistrationProcess>
                {
                    new RegistrationProcess()
                    {
                        PaidInFull = source.RegistrationProcess.Select(o => o.HasPaid),
                        
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

I am not sure how to set up the mapping for the RegistrationProcess.
I want to map PaidInFull within RegistrationProcess to the property HasPaid.  They are both bools.
I am getting an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool?>' to 'bool?'
I feel like I need to add something to the end of the Select statement but I am not sure what.  I did FirstOrDefault() and that made the error go away but I only got one value back and that is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are only creating one instance of `RegistrationProcess` inside the list constructor. So by calling `source.RegistrationProcess.Select(o => o.HasPaid)`  and assign it to your newly created `RegistrationProcess` you are creating a Collection of all bool values of your service registration process and try to assign it to a single registration process.

The Solution is to create multiple `RegistrationProcess` instances. In fact, one for each element in `source.RegistrationProcess`. To do this you can use the Select method on `source.RegistrationProcess` directly:

```
source.RegistrationProcesses.Select(x => new RegistrationProcess() { PaidInFull = x.HasPaid }).ToList()
```

As you can see, for every element in `source.RegistrationProcesses` a new `RegistrationProcess` is created. Or in other words: you select the elements of `source.RegistrationProcesses` as `new RegistrationProcess() { PaidInFull = x.HasPaid }` if that makes more sense to you.
The `.ToList()` converts the IEnumerable to a list.